# register with webform in uber cart drupal 7

Tags: 7, users, ubercart, webforms

Im trying to build a site with custom roles which are sold as memberships.

I've created my uber cart install and tested it. The rules defined allow the User to be assigned to the desired role upon completing a payment.

But the role membership should only be available to new users so im trying to unify the registration/uber cart checkout process

ive got some ubercart/webform module that allows me to have a webform in the checkout pane.

The problem im having is trying to hook the webform up to the registration process, i need some kind of rule to create a user account and login the visitor the new account one the payment is marked received.

I know there is some modules for dr6 to do this but im using dr7,

any help appreciated on figuring this out, im looking into using field collection/tokens/entities but maybe im over complicating it? maybe there is a direct hack into the .tpl i could do to insert the details from the webform into the user table?

Comment: May be the weborm rules integration is helpfull for you: http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules

Comment: Tried Looking at that but couldnt configure the rules to actually add the new user